# result of if condition that check text of textView

Tags: android, string, text

there are some problem in result of if condition that check the text of textView

this is the code for more explain

times.xml

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/tiMinutesView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"            
            android:text="--"
            android:textColor="#3134E8" />
```

TimesActivity.java

```
   TextView minView;                                
   minView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tiMinutesView);

    if (minView.getText().toString().trim() != "--") {

        Toast.makeText(TimesActivity.this,
                "OK",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(TimesActivity.this,
                "NO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
```

Now it is supposed to return false and display NO because it is equal "--" actually, but it returns true and display OK

What is the problem ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use `equals()` method for `String` **value** comparison.

```
if (!minView.getText().toString().trim().equals("--")) {
....
}
```

`==` is used for comparing the object references. `equals()` is the one used for value comparisons.

**P.S:-** There are like a **zillion** questions here @ SO, which explain this in more detail. Do refer them for more clarity.

Comment: Oh no!! at the same instant!! lol! I was early by 2 secs hahaha!

Comment: @Nezam - No issues! Let SO decide that, Cheers!

Comment: Nice!! it's working now .. that's because i am php developer and new to android
thanks alot :)

Comment: @AhmedGalal - No problem! Always, happy to help. If it solved your problem, do upvote & accept the answer, for future visitors to refer.

Answer (score 2):

You're on Java dude, so change the relevant line to:

```
    if (minView.getText().toString().trim().equals("--")) 
    {
    //write your code here.
}...
```

Answer (score 1):

always compare string using equals() of the string value/object.

```
if(!minView.getText().toString().trim().equals("--")){

}....
```

this will compare the value and `minView.getText().toString().trim() != "--"` this will compare the two string object

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
if (!minView.getText().toString().trim().equals("--")
```

instread of using

```
if (minView.getText().toString().trim() != "--")
```